# Cannot exit from multithreading for loop

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I can not break the following function if an error occurs.

```
def run(self, max_workers=10):
    outputs = {}

    q = queue.Queue()
    for key, ground_truth in self.ground_truths.items():
        q.put((key, ground_truth))

    count = {}
    count['total_finish'] = 0
    start_time = time.time()

    def worker():
        while True:
            try:
                key, value = self.pred_on_one_image(q.get())
                outputs[key] = value
                count['total_finish'] += 1
            except:
                os._exit()
            finally:
                q.task_done()

    for i in range(max_workers):
        t = Thread(target=worker)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    q.join()

    return outputs
```

I tried to use `return`, `q.put(None)`, `sys.exit()`, but all of them not work, I have to manually `Ctrl+C` to break it.

Answer (score 0):

`quit()` and `exit()` usually work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Set `q.get(block=False)` to raise `Empty` Exception if queue is empty. Otherwise, the queue will wait until the item is available in Queue. The default value of `block` is True, therefore, the queue was being blocked and no exception was raised.